# How should a news reader read the text when a quote of word/s is included?

Tags: reading, quoting

When there is no consensus  with content being read  in a report, the reporter  occasionally places a part of suspect text under quotes. Like for example in usage "safe" shelter where safety of structure was allegedly compromised...

One reads it as *quote unquote  safe* shelters are expensive etc...

However I think it should read *quote safe unquote* shelters are expensive etc... where the  circumspect part should be included making it more clear for the listener.

I have heard  it being  read either way but not sure which is one correct. What is the correct way to news read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As Collins states, either way is fine:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/quote-unquote-quote-unquote)

> You can say *quote* before and *unquote* after a word or phrase, or *quote, unquote* before or after it, to show that you are quoting someone or that you do not believe that a word or phrase used by others is accurate.

Anecdotally, I think that "quote ... unquote" around a phrase is more common when quoting several words, and "quote-unquote" before a phrase is more common when only one or two words are being enclosed in quotation marks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.